PowerBI column from text column
How to create a date/time column from text column with below formats
Current Format: 2024-03-12 04:15:26.732 UTC
Expected Format: 23 March 2024

To return a text field with that format, Add column, custom column, with
= Date.ToText(Date.FromText(Text.Start([Column1],10) ,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd"]),[Format="dd MMM yyyy"])

To return a date format that you can then manipulate with transform .. date... menu
= Date.FromText(Text.Start([Column1],10) ,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd"])

